# Contact Form 7 not submitting when on mobile

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, mobile, contact-form-7

I am using Contact Form 7. I have discovered that if I use the file upload input and am on mobile the form will not submit. here is the form code.

```
[text* full-name placeholder "Full Name"]
[email* your-email placeholder "Email"]
[tel* phone placeholder "Phone Number"]
<div class="input-wrapper">
[text* city class:input-city placeholder "City"]<span class="styled-select">[select* state class:input-state include_blank data:us_subdivisions.states]</span>
</div>
<div class="upload-wrapper">
[file applicants-resume id:fileuploadfield class:fileuploadfield filetypes:pdf|doc|docx id:applicants-resume][text uploadtextfield id:uploadtextfield class:uploadtextfield placeholder "Resume(PDF,Doc)"]<input type="button" id="uploadbrowsebutton" value="Browse">
</div>
[hidden position-id id:position-id "Position ID"]
[submit "Submit"]
```

I have been searching online and have found other people with this issue but no solution so far. Any help is much appreciated.

UPDATE: I have discovered it will work if there is a file attached i.e. the field has something in it. If the field is empty it will not work.

Comment: does the form work on mobile w/o the file upload field? if you write a plain form w/ upload from scratch, does it work from mobile?

Comment: yes, the form works on mobile if there is no file uploaded field

Comment: It's quite important to note which 'mobile' you're referring to. IOS has tons of issues when it comes to files.

Comment: I am currently testing on an IOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I was able to put together a hack. One person suggested this.

```
$("input[type=file]").each(function() {
   if($(this).val() === "") {
     $(this).remove();
   }
  });
```

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/when-typefile-is-set-in-contact-form-7-it-does-not-work-with-safari-ver-11-1/

I had to modify that approach. I had to add code for when the users try to submit an invalid form. here is what I came up with:

```
$('body').on('click', '.wpcf7-submit', function(e){

        $("input[type=file]").each(function() {
           if($(this).val() === "") {
             $(this).remove();
           }
        });

    });

document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7invalid', function( event ) {

        if ( 'XXXX' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {

            if( $(".fileuploadfield").parents(".applicants-resume").length == 1 ) {
                // we have a file
            } else {
                $('.applicants-resume').append('<input type="file" name="applicants-resume" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file wpcf7-validates-as-required fileuploadfield" id="fileuploadfield" accept=".pdf,.doc,.docx" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">');
            }

        }

    }, false );
```

The first part of the code removes the file input if it is empty. This allows Safari IOS to submit the form.

Next, I check if the form has errors using Contact Form 7's event handler wpcf7invalid.

If it has errors, I check to see if the file input exists or was it removed. If it was removed I add it back to the form so the user can upload a file on their next consecutive attempt.

The XXXX represent the form ID.

I hope this helps anyone else having issues with Contact Form 7 using a file input on mobile.